# INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS clause using python variables

Tags: python, mysql, praw

I am attempting to write an SQL query to insert rows into a table when the script is run. I have been able to get it working whilst duplicating data, but am unable to set up an insert that can determine whether or not the record is unique.

I have tried following these threads:

[Most efficient way to do a SQL 'INSERT IF NOT EXISTS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721656/most-efficient-way-to-do-a-sql-insert-if-not-exists)

[Python MySQLdb / MySQL INSERT IGNORE & Checking if Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801227/python-mysqldb-mysql-insert-ignore-checking-if-ignored)

Currently, I can get the system to add all records, but due to the frequency the script is ran at the database is being filled with the same records. This is my current code:

```
for post in r.get_subreddit("listentothis").get_new(limit=5):
if 'youtube.com' in post.url or 'youtu.be' in post.url:
    print(str(post.title))
    print(str(post.url))
sql = """INSERT INTO listentothis2(title,url) VALUES ('%s', '%s') WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM listentothis2 WHERE url = '%s') """ % (post.title, post.url, post.url)
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
```

I have also tried:

```
sql = """INSERT IGNORE INTO listentothis2(title,url) VALUES ('%s', '%s') """ % (post.title, post.url)
```

However, this adds the 3 most recent records whether or not they are commited to the database already. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The technique you're after is called 'upsert', and the mysql version `insert ... on duplicate key update` syntax is described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Theres still a couple of faults (first record found not being added etc) but this completes what I want to do! Thanks so much for the speedy reply!